# Scrollbars not visible + Events not thrown

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to implement a userControl which is able to scroll and zoom with provided mouse input.

Therefore, I implemented following user Control. (If its working I am going to move the Events directly to the Model)

**ScrollDragZoomControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MinimalMonitoringClient.Controls.ScrollDragZoomControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MinimalMonitoringClient.Controls.Models"
         Background="Transparent">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <models:ScrollDragZoomViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>

<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer"
              MouseLeftButtonUp="scrollViewer_MouseLeftButtonUp"
              PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="scrollViewer_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
              PreviewMouseWheel="scrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel"
              PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="scrollViewer_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
              MouseMove="scrollViewer_MouseMove"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}">

    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <Viewbox>
            <!-- Present the actual stuff the user wants to display -->
            <ContentPresenter />
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

In another UserControl I would like to use this UserControl so show Content which could be bigger than the current UserControl's width and height. For Testing I set Width and Height to something huge.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MinimalMonitoringClient.Panels.HierarchicalView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:panels="clr-namespace:MinimalMonitoringClient.Models.Panels"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MinimalMonitoringClient.Controls">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <panels:HierarchicalViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>

<controls:ScrollDragZoomControl>
    <Image Source="/Images/Information.png" Width="2000" Height="2000" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
</controls:ScrollDragZoomControl>
```

1. No Events are called in the ScrollDragZoomControl. I set the
   Background to transparent. Also played with IsHitTestVisible.
2. The Scrollbars are not visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the `Content` property of the `UserControl` to an `Image` element you effectively "override" any content that you have defined in `ScrollDragZoomControl.xaml`.

You probably want the `ScrollViewer` and the rest of the stuff you have defined in `ScrollDragZoomControl.xaml` to be part of the UserControl's *template*:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MinimalMonitoringClient.Controls.ScrollDragZoomControl"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
     xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MinimalMonitoringClient.Controls.Models"
     Background="Transparent">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <panels:HierarchicalViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer"
              MouseLeftButtonUp="scrollViewer_MouseLeftButtonUp"
              PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="scrollViewer_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
              PreviewMouseWheel="scrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel"
              PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="scrollViewer_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
              MouseMove="scrollViewer_MouseMove"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}">

                <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform />
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                    <Viewbox>
                        <!-- Present the actual stuff the user wants to display -->
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Viewbox>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm. So the <ContentPresenter /> Just overrides the UserControls ContentTemplate. Therefore, the actual Content (ScrollView) isn't visible anymore. I didn't know that :)